# pig latin - count distinct and group by

Tags: apache-pig

I have a data set (userid, resH, resW)

with data such as

```
(1001, 800, 600)
(1001, 800, 600)
(1002, 900, 700)
(1003, 900, 700)
(1004, 1800, 600)
(1005, 1800, 1600)
```

I want to get the count of distinct users in each group of resH-reshW.

e.g the output with above data would be

```
800,  600, 1
900,  700, 2
1800, 600, 1
1800, 1600, 1
```

I tried something like

```
D = group data by (resH,resW);
E = foreach D { 
    unique = DISTINCT data.userId;
    generate group, COUNT(unique) as unique_cnt;
};
```

But I didn't get what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way output was required:-

```
Alias1 = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (userid:int,resH:int,resW:int);
Alias2 = DISTINCT Alias1;
Alias3 = GROUP Alias2 BY (resH,resW);
Alias4 = foreach Alias3 GENERATE flatten(group),flatten(COUNT(Alias2.userid)) ;
DUMP Alias4;
or 
STORE Alias4 INTO 'output.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: do we need the FLATTEN for the COUNT too?

Comment: Its optional, flatten is written here to just show output in pretty format.

Answer (score 1):

Load the data and then distinct it out to remove duplicates,then group by the two columns of interest and count the userids.

```
A = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (userid:int,resH:int,resW:int);
B = DISTINCT A;
C = GROUP B BY (resH,resW);
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (resH,resW),COUNT(A.userid);
DUMP D;
```

Comment: which version of pig you are using ?, D step does give syntax error.

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "" at line 6, column 33.

Comment: line 6 column 33 is the character after 'group as '

Comment: @Anand. Use Flatten for group to split it up into two columns.